# How to loop through and copy every row of large MySQL table?

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql

## Scenario:

I have a MySQL MyISAM table (table1) with 11 million rows, all of which I want to copy to a better table (table2, which has the InnoDB engine along with the proper indices). Since adding indexes to the MyISAM table simply takes too long I want to loop through the entire table and copy every row to the new table.

Is there a way to do this within MySQL?

## Conditions:

- There is no time limit to this action (could be looped "slowly").
- The tables have the same columns.
- table1 is online and needs to stay online (being read all the time; I've temporarily paused writing).

## Problems:

- MySQL server is a shared host (no file system access).
- Mysqldump times out.
- Adding an index times out.
- Simply inserting a select of the previous table times out.

## Idea:

Perhaps one could loop this as a MySQL statement, doing 10 000 at a time or something like that?

This works for one (1) record:

```
INSERT INTO products_indexed
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE products.p_product_id=(
    SELECT products.p_product_id AS id FROM products
    LEFT OUTER JOIN products_indexed ON (
        products.p_product_id = products_indexed.p_product_id
    )
    WHERE products_indexed.p_product_id IS NULL
    LIMIT 1
)
```

This could then be looped using a stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE x  INT; 
SET x = 1;

WHILE x  <= 1000000 DO
SET  x = x + 1; 

INSERT INTO products_indexed
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE products.p_product_id=(
    SELECT products.p_product_id AS id FROM products
    LEFT OUTER JOIN products_indexed ON (
        products.p_product_id = products_indexed.p_product_id
    )
    WHERE products_indexed.p_product_id IS NULL
    LIMIT 1
);

END WHILE;

END
```

This is probably not the best way to loop through, but it's a try. Seems to work, but how would I optimize it? (Perhaps do the query to get a couple of thousand rows and then do the INSERTs?

Comment: What utility are you running that is forcing a timeout?

Comment: @RickJames I'm running mysql to the server via OS X Terminal and some database apps.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html

```
To convert a non-InnoDB table to use InnoDB use ALTER TABLE:

ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: ALTER TABLE makes the query timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`pt-online-schema-change`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html). It has an example for exactly what you're looking for:

```
pt-online-schema-change --alter "ENGINE=InnoDB" D=sakila,t=actor
```

As the name suggests, it will perform the change online with no locking by creating a duplicate table and doing an atomic rename as the last step.

It's hard to say whether you'll experience the same locking issues, but hopefully not!